# Does Unreal Engine store its dependencies in the file itself?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, unreal-engine4

I have 2 unreal-engine installations in the same user . The size of the first installation is 5gb larger (around 21 GB) . But my guide has helped me setup several changes in the second installation . Will it be safe to delete the first installation ? 
Is it so that Unreal Engine installs its dependencies in the folder itself ; so when installed for the 2nd time some dependencies were used from the 1st folder? If that is the case how do i remove my 1st folder without affecting the 2nd one?

Answer (score 1):

Simply try renaming the folder of the first installation and look if the second does still work.